# How to track down a process or potential virus that is eating my bandwidth on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, router, internet, bandwidth, virus-removal

I'll try my best to explain. I was on a rush today, so I downloaded something from a source I didn't know. I didn't double check (yep, my bad) and run the executable.

I didn't **explicitly** run it as an administrator mode, but the **User Account Control** window asking **Do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to make changes to your PC?** popped up (so maybe that message means the app is asking for admins? if that's the case RIP me).

So I clicked **Yes** and the problem began. When that PC is connected to the WiFi, every other PC gets a `ping` response of over 200ms to the gateway router `192.168.1.1` and a 200ms to 1.2s to `8.8.8.8`. Subsequently, by running `speedtest.net` said PC gets a download speed of about 1 Mbps while the other 2 PCs and 1 Mac gets 6 Mbps.

Obviously something in my PC is eating bandwidth. Problem is I'm unable to track it down. The **Task Manager** doesn't show any process with a high network consumption nor the **Performance** shows 0 Kbps send and received.

I'm using Avast antivirus which didn't find anything after a full system scan.

I ran out of ideas, how do I track down this thing?

**EDIT**: did a system restore for one of 3 days ago. Made no difference.

Comment: how about sysinternals process explorer used to view the process that is using network bandwidth (look it up how to use it for that)

Comment: In addition to the sysinternals tools, look at your router logs too and confirm that it is indeed that IP that has lots going on with your data network. You could also run Wireshark and trace all TCP/IP running on the machine and see what's going on.

Comment: worth noting that wireshark won't show process name

Comment: Also, it might be more malware than a virus.  My guess is that the software changed your registry in some way to automatically let it run.  Try some other anti-malware software as well.  Typically no single malware solution captures them all.  If you have a previous version of your registry it might be worth rolling back to that if possible.

Comment: @Dale you write "Also, it might be more malware than a virus." <-- what do you mean? I'm not sure that proper Viruses are  really written anymore.  Where you find multiple files get infected by the thing as it copies itself and 'multiplies'. So if you distinguish virus from malware and presumably you don't mean a virus in the sense of infecting lots of executables, then how are you defining virus?

Comment: Let me clear things up a bit.  Some anti-virus programs ONLY look at viruses.  My only point was to say that you may wish to try other scanning software to possibly find the culprit. I've had spyware on my system that didn't go away until I ended up using some anti-malware software to remove it.

Comment: Any recommendations? I was using Avast because it had really good reviews, but apparently it doesn't do its job. Oh btw, I updated my question.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? I specifically made sure my question follow every guideline for posting on superuser...

Comment: When investigating in Task Manager ensure that "Show processes from all users" is ticked

Comment: I upvoted you out of a negative.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I would recommend trying some other anti-virus programs.  I use Norton Security.  While Norton used to be just terrible because it was impossible to remove, it has become a  top notch software package which includes a wide array of software packages designed to protect you from viruses, malware, phishing schemes, spyware etc.  It also has an excellent firewall as well as identity protection.  Typically you can find an excellent deal online to get 10 licences for your house for about $40 to $50.  You may have to search around a bit for a coupon code but you can usually get

Answer (score 1):

1. Start Task Manger (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>)
2. Select the Performance tab
3. Click the Resource Monitor... button at the bottom of the tab
4. When Resource Monitor starts click the Network tab
5. Investigate all the Processes with Network Activity to locate the offending process

If you are unsure about a particular process you can right click on it and Search Online for more information on that process:

[image]